# Using .zero? instead of ==0?

Tags: ruby

Am I missing something simple or am I using `.zero?` in a situation it isn't supposed to be used in?

This works:

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  puts(num%15==0 ? "FizzBuzz" : num%5==0 ? "Buzz" : num% 3==0 ? "Fizz" : num)
end
```

This doesn't:

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  puts(num%15.zero? "FizzBuzz" : num%5.zero? "Buzz" : num% 3.zero? "Fizz" : num)
end
```

I get the following errors when I use the second code block:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
...o ? "FizzBuzz" : num%5.zero?  "Buzz" : num%3.zero?  "Fizz" :...
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
...zzBuzz" : num%5.zero?  "Buzz" : num%3.zero?  "Fizz" : num
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator uses a `?`. The question mark in `zero?` is part of the name of the method, not the ternary operator. Something else: the `zero?`method is executed on 15, 5, 3 respectively, not on `num%15` etc. Below is the correct version. The first version is much cleaner.

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  puts((num%15).zero? ? "FizzBuzz" : (num%5).zero? ? "Buzz" : (num% 3).zero? ? "Fizz" : num)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The use of multiple ternary statements to provide a complex conditional test is discouraged in Ruby. It results in code that is difficult to read and maintain. Instead of using:

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  puts(num%15==0 ? "FizzBuzz" : num%5==0 ? "Buzz" : num% 3==0 ? "Fizz" : num)
end
```

Use something like:

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  response = if num % 15 == 0
              'FizzBuzz'
            elsif num % 5 == 0
              'Buzz'
            elsif num % 3 == 0
              'Fizz'
            else
              num
            end
  puts response
end
```

Or better, use a `case` statement to get rid of the chained `elsif`:

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  response = case 
             when num % 15 == 0
               'FizzBuzz'
             when num % 5 == 0
               'Buzz'
             when num % 3 == 0
               'Fizz'
             else
               num
             end
  puts response
end
```

It's easy to see what is happening, to see the conditional tests and determine the values being returned when the code is broken out this way.

Comment: Thank you for that second example. I was trying to put it together without actually writing out the If/else statement.